# DateTime Conversion to Unix Epoch Adding Phantom Hour

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have the following conversion methods for converting to and from Unix Epoch timestamps

```
public static class DateTimeHelpers
{
    public static DateTime UnixEpoch()
    {
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }

    public static DateTime FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(long milliseconds)
    {
        return UnixEpoch().AddMilliseconds(milliseconds).ToLocalTime();
    }

    public static long ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (long)(dateTime - UnixEpoch()).TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

The problem is (boy this seems like basic stuff), I set a `DateTime` I want and then try to convert to Unix-Time but the returned milliscond timestamp is +01:00 hour, I want to know why?

The code I am using is

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

long startMillis = DateTimeHelpers.ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(startDate);
```

this gives `startMillis = 1443657600000` which is "Thursday October 01, 2015 01:00:00 (am) in time zone Europe/London (BST)". I want a timestamp back from `ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch` that is "2015/10/01 00:00:00", what am I missing here?

Thanks for your time.

---

Edit. I want to do the equivelant of some Java code. This produced the *right* timestamp. Why can I do this in Java and not C#? Anyway the code

```
private static long ukTimeStringToUtcMillis(String s) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = makeSimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    try {
        return sdf.parse(s).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static SimpleDateFormat makeSimpleDateFormat(String s) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(s);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    return sdf;
}
```

I use it like this

```
long timestamp = ukTimeStringToUtcMillis("2015-10-01T00:00:00.000");
```

this gives `timestamp = 1443654000000` which is "Thursday October 01, 2015 00:00:00 (am) in time zone Europe/London (BST)". What am I missing with C#? I have tried

```
var ukTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
DateTime unixEpoch = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), ukTimeZone, ukTimeZone);

long startMillis = (long)(startDate - unixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
long endMillis = (long)(endDate - unixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
```

This ADDS an hour!?

Comment: `Europe/London (BST)` isn't `UTC +01:00` right now? Isn't this normal to return `Oct 01 2015 01:00:00`? http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php?epoch=1443657600

Comment: I am attempting to do a C# equivalent of some Java. I have edited the question. If you could cast you eye over it it would be most appreciated!

Comment: `return UnixEpoch().AddMilliseconds(milliseconds).ToLocalTime();` you did not start with local time, so returning localtime will include the TZ offset.  Return UTC and it makes the round trip fine.

Comment: I'm not querying that section of the code although you might be right, I have been playing around a fair bit. I have an issue with getting the C# equivalent of my Java (see edit). I can't for love-nor-money get the correct millisecond timestamp using C#!?

Comment: I can get it to make the roundtrip fine fixing that; without it, I have a several hour variance.  I cant see for sure in the source, but I think DateTime looks at and adjusts for Kind: `ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch` returns the same value for UTC and Local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- If possible, you should work with `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` for this type of operation.  `DateTimeOffset` is always a specific moment in time, while `DateTime` *might* be, or might not be, depending on `Kind` and how well you adhere to the subtleties of how `Kind` is interpreted by various methods.
- If you do use `DateTimeOffset`, and you are targeting .NET 4.6 or greater (or .NET Core), then you can use the built in [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds.aspx) and [`ToUnixTimeMilliseconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds.aspx) methods, rather than creating your own.
- You might consider using the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) open source library, as it adds significant value to most applications working with date and time.

  - For instance, if you want to work with tzdb time zones like the `"Europe/London"` zone you mentioned, then you can use `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"]`.

Now the rest of my answer assumes you don't take any of the above recommendations, and pertains to the code you provided in the question.

- You have `UnixEpoch` implemented as a static method.  Since its value never changes, it should probably be implemented as a static property, with a private readonly backing field.  It could also be implemented as a public static readonly field, though most people prefer exposing those via properties.  (These are just coding guidelines, but don't introduce any error.)
- In your `FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch` method, you are calling `.ToLocalTime()`.  That should be omitted.  You don't need to call `.ToUniversalTime()` either.  Just return the result of adding the milliseconds.  The `Kind` will be `Utc`.  If you need to work with local time, do the conversion later - not inside this function.
- Recognize that the ID `"GMT Standard Time"` is for London, not UTC.  London is either GMT (UTC+00:00) or BST (UTC+01:00) depending on the date and time in question.
- Recognize that `DateTime.ToLocalTime` and `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` convert between UTC and the current local time zone on the machine where the code is running.  That might be London, or might be something else depending on your use case.  If you're running on a *server*, such as in an ASP.Net web application, then it's not a good practice to rely on the system local time zone.
- In the code you showed with `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`, since you didn't assign `DateTimeKind.Utc` to the input, that value will have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  `ConvertTime` will interpret that as already belonging to the source time zone.  Since you've given the same destination time zone, then in most cases this will be a no-op.
- In that same function, it's invalid to define `unixEpoch` in terms of London time, for the reasons specified earlier.  Also note that on 1970-01-01, London was not on GMT, but actually on BST (known as "British Standard Time" back then, rather than "British Summer time").  TZDB knows about this, but it's too far back for Windows time zones and `TimeZoneInfo`.  The `"GMT Standard Time"` Windows zone only reflects the current rules around BST/GMT, not those that were in effect at the time.

As far as converting the Java code you supplied, that function reads a string in ISO 8601 format with millisecond precision, interprets it in the London time zone, converts it to UTC, and gives the time in milliseconds since the Unix epoch.  There are a few ways you could do that:

- .Net 3.5+

  ```
  public static long UkTimeStringToUtcMillis(string s)
  {
      string format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF";
      DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
      DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, tz);
      DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
      return (long) (utc - epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
  }
  ```
- .Net 4.6+ / .Net CoreCLR

  ```
  public static long UkTimeStringToUtcMillis(string s)
  {
      string format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF";
      DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
      TimeSpan offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(dt);
      DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
      return dto.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
  }
  ```
- Noda Time

  ```
  public static long UkTimeStringToUtcMillis(string s)
  {
      LocalDateTimePattern pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern;
      LocalDateTime dt = pattern.Parse(s).Value;
      DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
      Instant i = dt.InZoneLeniently(tz).ToInstant();
      return i.Ticks / NodaConstants.TicksPerMillisecond;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. It is most appreciated and really helped me understand this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If I follow what you are doing, your test code starts with UTC time:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

But in `FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch` you return LocalTime.  Using the code as is, it wont make a roundtrip:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToUniversalTime());
Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(dt), 
    FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(dt)));
```

> 10/1/2015 5:00:00 AM
>   1443657600000  10/1/2015 12:00:00 AM

If I change `FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch`:

```
public static DateTime FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(long milliseconds)
{
    return UnixEpoch().AddMilliseconds(milliseconds).ToUniversalTime();
}
```

Now it will make the roundtrip:

> 10/1/2015 5:00:00 AM
>   1443675600000  10/1/2015 5:00:00 AM

Note than the MilliSecondsSince is the same for each.  You cant just look at that because there is no context.

I could not find it in the Ref Source, but surely DateTime is smart enough to adjust when the TZs are different before subtracting.  (Otherwise it is hard to explain how `1443675600000` can represent 3 TimeSpans for the same date (2 for me and one for you).

Comment: AThanks very much for your reply. You time is most appreciated. I appologise if I have misled you here. I am aware that it is impossible to make a round trip with local time present. This was added when I was playing about... The problem is getting the millisecond timestamp for 2015/10/01 00:00:00. When I create `new DateTime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0)` and try to get the timestamp in UNIX epoch, it gives the timestamp for "2015/10/01 01:00:00" why? How do I get the timestamp for 00:00:00, why is it adding an hour, I am doing nothing with `ToLocalTime()`?

Comment: The millisecs since (1443675600000 )  includes the TZ offset for the local machine. This is why a DateTime created as UTC or Local returns the same Unix elapsed value.  The same number of MS have elapsed whether the time was UTC, BST or anything else.